# error compiling c++11 program with clang on windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, c++11, clang

I have built clang 3.2 on windows and was trying to build a simple hello world program. But I get a lots of errors like the one seen below.

```
d:\Marius\xyz>clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -Wall xyz.cpp -o xyz.exe
clang++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-stdlib=libc++'
In file included from xyz.cpp:12:
In file included from ./stdafx.h:18:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\algorithm:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0:9:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xutility:8:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\utility:8:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\type_traits:1072:
33: error:
  '_Ty' does not refer to a value
            _HAS_TRIVIAL_MOVE_CONSTRUCTOR(_Ty)
                                          ^

...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xstddef:540:50: note:
      expanded from macro '_VARIADIC_EXPAND_4'
#define _VARIADIC_EXPAND_4(FUNC, X1, X2, X3, X4) \
                                                 ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xrefwrap:222:22:note:
      expanded from macro '_CLASS_RESULT_OF_PMF_OPT_0X'
                        __thiscall, X2, X3, X4)
                                          ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

I get lots of errors like that, coming from VC++ 2012 headers. Is it possible at all to build C++11 code with clang++ on Windows? Do I have to provide additional command switches?

Comment: `-fms-extensions` maybe.

Comment: According to the user manual (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) that flag is enabled by default. I also tried setting -fmsc-version=1700 (that is VS2012) and even -fdelayed-template-parsing (which also should be the default). No result. Removing the stdafx.h has no effect on the compilation errors.

Comment: I also tried using mingw headers with -isystem, but this looks like a config nightmare. Depending on the order of the includes I get different errors and haven't been able to setup an order without compilation errors.

Comment: @Mat there's nothing Microsoft-specific about stdafx.h. It's a project-specific file that's entirely standards-compliant. The Visual Studio compiler just caches the compiled output if you turn on certain options.

Answer (score 3):

Clang does not work properly when built by Visual Studio (supposedly it works when built by MinGW, but I haven't been able to verify that myself).

When Clang is built, it is configured to use the library used to build it. Since you built Clang using Visual Studio, Clang will try to use the Visual Studio headers and libraries. Unfortunately, the internals of Clang and Visual Studio are different enough that Clang *can't* use the VS-specific headers.

Until [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) can be compiled for Windows, Clang will (almost certainly) never work when compiled by Visual Studio. Try building it using MinGW (and make a blog post or something on how you did it!), and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

clang defaults to the includes of the toolchain used to built it. But as in the case of MS, extensions used maybe vendor-specific. clang's own libc++ availability is expected to greatly alleviate the issue. Manually specify correct include dirs.

Also separate compile and link stages during build. This will cause linking to be with correct binary libs than the VS defaults.